# How to merge deteched commits to master

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I tried to create new branch from a certain commit of master. I don't remember the command I used but I think this one (but not sure)

```
git branch branchname <sha1-of-commit>
```

I got a new branch with a bunch of commits. But I found that master branch lost all commits that found in new branch. Changes related with lost commits were also lost in master branch.

It looks like I detached a bunch of commits from master to new branch. Actually I never wanted master branch to lost its commits. How can I restore those detached commit to master?

Please see the illustration of my problem below:

[image: Some random commits were detached to new branch]

Comment: `But I found that master branch lost all commits that found in new branch` ... no, that doesn't sound right.  Creating a new branch from some point in `master` shouldn't be adding/removing commits from `master`.  Are you certain of what you have told us?

Comment: I just want to create new branch from some point in master. But I may have used wrong command. Someone may figure out what I have done by seeing my problem.

Comment: Removing commits from `master` is way harder than what you did, and I'm not sure your diagram is accurate.  But your command to create a new branch from a specific commit looks right.

Comment: The odd thing is that I can still checkout to a lost commit state in master and there I can see my lost commits. It just disappeared in master branch log. Thanks for your comments and paying attention.

Comment: What you are describing seems more consistent with your having done this: `git branch <sha1-of-commit>` ... did you checkout an old commit from your branch in the detached HEAD state?

Comment: Did you run `git reset` which could make `master` move to an unexpected commit? Try `git reflog master` to find out the right head of `master` and what happened to `master`.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the output of `git log`. Try `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` (remember this as "get help from A DOG, All Decorate Oneline Graph").

Comment: Output of `git reflog` will be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Commit 4, 7, 8, 10 and 13 are on the new branch and you want them to be in master instead.

You can't move into a detached HEAD state, with that command above, you will you will have to do

```
git checkout <sha-1 of commit>
```

OR

```
git checkout branchname
```

So its most likely you ran another commit that has messed things, use

```
git reflog
```

to try and find out where things went wrong.

However, if you ran the right command, and you can't remember. To merge that branch back into master.

**1/ Do a checkout to commit 13,** I am assuming that's the final commit you made on the detached HEAD state.

```
git checkout <sha-1 of commit 13>
```

**2/ Give that branch a name,** this means give this branch a name, that makes checkout to it later easier.If you do run

```
git branch -a
```

You'll get something like this

```
(detached from <sha-1 of commit 13)
master
*Other branches
```

To rename the branch do;

```
git checkout -b <branch-name>
```

Then list the branches again

```
<branch-name>
master
*Other branches
```

**3/ Merging is easy now,** simply checkout to your master branch and merge

```
git checkout master
git merge <branch-name>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Happy to help!!